# My webserver just got hacked

Tags: security, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My server's been hacked EMERGENCY](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency)

My web server just got hacked.  It was on a vps so I think it was hacked through another site.

When I loaded the homepage it looks like it ran some script.

Can anyone tell me if this script is malicious and if I just got screwed by my own website?

```
`<script>var _0x8ae2=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x7A\x6F\x6E\x65\x2D\x68\x2E\x6F\x72\x67\x2F\x61\x72\x63\x68\x69\x76\x65\x2F\x6E\x6F\x74\x69\x66\x69\x65\x72\x3D\x54\x69\x47\x45\x52\x2D\x4D\x25\x34\x30\x54\x45","\x6F\x70\x65\x6E","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x7A\x6F\x6E\x65\x2D\x68\x2E\x6F\x72\x67\x2F\x61\x72\x63\x68\x69\x76\x65\x2F\x6E\x6F\x74\x69\x66\x69\x65\x72\x3D\x54\x69\x47\x45\x52\x2D\x4D\x25\x34\x30\x54\x45\x2F\x73\x70\x65\x63\x69\x61\x6C\x3D\x31","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6C\x6D\x67\x74\x66\x79\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F\x3F\x71\x3D\x48\x61\x63\x6B\x65\x64\x20\x62\x79\x20\x54\x69\x47\x45\x52\x2D\x4D\x25\x34\x30\x54\x45","\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x42\x79","\x74\x69\x74\x6C\x65","\x48\x61\x63\x6B\x65\x44\x20\x42\x79\x20\x54\x69\x47\x45\x52\x2D\x4D\x40\x54\x45","\x6F\x6E\x6B\x65\x79\x64\x6F\x77\x6E","\x72\x65\x73\x69\x7A\x65\x54\x6F","\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x54\x6F","\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x28\x29","\x72\x6F\x75\x6E\x64","\x66\x67\x43\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72","\x62\x67\x43\x6F\x6C\x6F\x72","\x4C\x4F\x4C","\x61\x76\x61\x69\x6C\x57\x69\x64\x74\x68","\x61\x76\x61\x69\x6C\x48\x65\x69\x67\x68\x74"];function details(){window[_0x8ae2[1]](_0x8ae2[0]);window[_0x8ae2[1]](_0x8ae2[2]);window[_0x8ae2[1]](_0x8ae2[3]);} ;window[_0x8ae2[4]](0,1);if(document[_0x8ae2[5]]==_0x8ae2[6]){function keypressed(){return false;} ;document[_0x8ae2[7]]=keypressed;window[_0x8ae2[8]](0,0);window[_0x8ae2[9]](0,0);setTimeout(_0x8ae2[10],2);var mxm=50;var mym=25;var mx=0;var my=0;var sv=50;var status=1;var szx=0;var szy=0;var c=255;var n=0;var sm=30;var cycle=2;var done=2;function move(){if(status==1){mxm=mxm/1.05;mym=mym/1.05;mx=mx+mxm;my=my-mym;mxm=mxm+(400-mx)/100;mym=mym-(300-my)/100;window[_0x8ae2[9]](mx,my);rmxm=Math[_0x8ae2[11]](mxm/10);rmym=Math[_0x8ae2[11]](mym/10);if(rmxm==0){if(rmym==0){status=2;} ;} ;} ;if(status==2){sv=sv/1.1;scrratio=1+1/3;mx=mx-sv*scrratio/2;my=my-sv/2;szx=szx+sv*scrratio;szy=szy+sv;window[_0x8ae2[9]](mx,my);window[_0x8ae2[8]](szx,szy);if(sv<0.1){status=3;} ;} ;if(status==3){document[_0x8ae2[12]]=0xffffFF;c=c-16;if(c<0){status=8;} ;} ;if(status==4){c=c+16;document[_0x8ae2[13]]=c*65536;document[_0x8ae2[12]]=(255-c)*65536;if(c>239){status=5;} ;} ;if(status==5){c=c-16;document[_0x8ae2[13]]=c*65536;document[_0x8ae2[12]]=(255-c)*65536;if(c<0){status=6;cycle=cycle-1;if(cycle>0){if(done==1){status=7;} else {status=4;} ;} ;} ;} ;if(status==6){document[_0x8ae2[5]]=_0x8ae2[14];alert(_0x8ae2[14]);cycle=2;status=4;done=1;} ;if(status==7){c=c+4;document[_0x8ae2[13]]=c*65536;document[_0x8ae2[12]]=(255-c)*65536;if(c>128){status=8;} ;} ;if(status==8){window[_0x8ae2[9]](0,0);sx=screen[_0x8ae2[15]];sy=screen[_0x8ae2[16]];window[_0x8ae2[8]](sx,sy);status=9;} ;var _0xceebx11=setTimeout(_0x8ae2[10],0.3);} ;} ;</script><body bgcolor="#000000" oncontextmenu="return false;"><p align="center"><span style="font-weight: 700;"><font face="Tahoma" size="5" color="#EEEEEE"><i>Server HackeD<br/><br/>By</i> </font><br/><br/><a href="#" class="name"><script>if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){document.write('<font face="Arial Black" size="5" color="#FF0000">');}else{document.write('<font face="Arial Black" size="5" color="black" style="text-shadow:#FFFFFF 2px 2px 5px">');}</script><i onclick="details()">TiGER-M@TE</i></font></a></span><br/><br/><script>var l1n3='<img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />';
```

document.write(l1n3+l1n3);`

Comment: yes, it is malicious.

Comment: It looks to me like it is going after some browser exploit.  I wonder which one.

Comment: It's a virus that infects Windows machines and modifies HTML files it can find. The idea is then for the administrator to unknowingly upload the modified files to their web server, then have the malicious JavaScript code run on the visitors' machines.

Comment: GOD DAMMIT how do I protect myself, and check it if it executed?

Comment: If it's a VPS you didn't get "hacked through another site". One of the big plusses of a VPS is that you're isolated from the other servers running on the same VM host.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that looks very suspicious.

Are you hosted with InMotion? Because this looks like the TiGERM@TE hack that just hit there a few hours ago: http://blastmagazine.com/the-magazine/technology/tech-news/computers/inmotion-hosting-servers-hacked-by-tiger-mte-blast-affected/ .

Contact your hosting provider and let them know the details.

**EDIT**: In the meantime, think what other sites you may have been logged in to when it was executed / when the page loaded (ie Facebook) and go and check that it hasn't been compromised (strange messages sent to friends, people added to your friend list etc). Often these scripts will use the fact that you're already signed in to popular sites to execute malicious commands via URLs that would only work if you were logged in. In the meantime, use a Javascript blocker on your browser of choice before visiting the malicious site (or the hosting companies site) again.

**EDIT 2**: A message from an InMotion hosting rep:

```
Hi Everyone,

This is Brad with InMotion Hosting. I just wanted to touch base and apologize 
for the rough Sunday morning some of you are having. I can definitely say that 
we know how you feel. Please be sure to check out our status page for updates –     
inmotionhosting.com/status

I do appreciate everyone’s patience. Our Support team is hard at work trying 
to answer everyone’s questions, and our Systems Team is hard at work tackling 
the issue.

Thanks,
- Brad
```

Comment: Yes I am with inmotion... Do you know anymore details on the hack? I can't get them on the phone obviously.

Comment: @billmalarky: Here's some info that might help you, it describes a fix for Wordpress based sites (which were the most commonly affected sites): http://dreamdare.org/blog/how-to-fix-inmotion-hosting-hack-tiger-mate/ .

Comment: @billmalarky: As per the InMotion rep, check out this site for more info: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/20110925-systems-announcement.html

Comment: I've fixed my website's index files, but I am quite concerned about the script that ran when I visited the webpage.  The last think I need to get malware from my own website. any thoughts as to how to protect myself?